# More than 1 facade class in 'facade design pattern'?

Tags: design-patterns, oop

Is it acceptable to make more than 1 facade *class* (not instance) in a facade design pattern?
I mean, is it formally forbidden ? 
Will it inhibit the 'facade design pattern' advantage itself?

Comment: I don't think anything is really formally forbidden, just frowned upon, (I'm not saying that what you propose is frowned upon, I'm just saying in general) As long as you write code that's clean, easy to read and understand and also works, then your okay. Your own reasoning should help you with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A facade is basically a convenient grouping of functionality. If multiple such groupings exist you may certainly make multiple facades.

Please note that when using dependency injection patterns usage of the facade pattern is far less common than earlier.